# Error When Trying to Run Simple Kivy Program (Windows)

Tags: python, kivy

When trying to run the following program on my computer:

```
# First import an App class from kivy
from kivy.app import App
# Define App subclass
class TutorialApp(App):
    pass
if __name__=="__main__":
    TutorialApp().run()
```

After I added what was suggested( The last two lines ), I get two syntax errors, the first telling me to delete the colon and the second telling me to remove the indent, and then this:

```
[INFO              ] Kivy v1.8.0
[INFO              ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\rabbitrabbit\.kivy       \logs\kivy_14-08-15_5.txt
[INFO              ] [Factory     ] 157 symbols loaded
[DEBUG             ] [Cache       ] register <kv.lang> with limit=None, timeout=Nones
[DEBUG             ] [Cache       ] register <kv.image> with limit=None, timeout=60s
[DEBUG             ] [Cache       ] register <kv.atlas> with limit=None, timeout=Nones
[INFO              ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif (img_pygame,  img_pil ignored)
[DEBUG             ] [Cache       ] register <kv.texture> with limit=1000, timeout=60s
[DEBUG             ] [Cache       ] register <kv.shader> with limit=1000, timeout=3600s
[DEBUG             ] [App         ] Loading kv <C:\Python33\tutorial.kv>
[DEBUG             ] [App         ] kv <C:\Python33\tutorial.kv> not found
[DEBUG             ] [Window      ] Ignored <egl_rpi> (import error)
[DEBUG             ] [Window      ] Ignored <pygame> (import error)
[WARNING           ] [WinPygame   ] SDL wrapper failed to import!
[DEBUG             ] [Window      ] Ignored <sdl> (import error)
[DEBUG             ] [Window      ] Ignored <x11> (import error)
[CRITICAL          ] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider at all!
[CRITICAL          ] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

According to the tutorial I'm following( http://inclem.net/2014/01/09/kivy-crash-course/1_making-a-simple-app/ ), the program should be able to run without problems. I've installed Kivy and Python 3.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're missing an install of `pygame` - it's not pulled in as a dependency by the Kivy install so you need to install it separately -- see http://kivy.org/docs/installation/troubleshooting-macosx.html#unable-to-find-any-valuable-window-provider-error

Answer (score 1):

If that's really your program, the problem is simply that it doesn't do anything. Use `TutorialApp().run()` to actually start the gui.

Either way, that traceback is not an error.

Comment: According to the tutorial I'm following( link in question), it should still be able to open and size a window without any problems.

Comment: With the code you just added, it should work, though you have the error that there are no spaces in those two lines, e.g. `if__name...` should be `if __name...`

Comment: I added the space and it helped with the if __name problem, but now it's saying it needs a window provider. I put the error in the edited post.

Comment: As the other answer says, you apparently don't have pygame available. How did you install kivy?

Comment: I installed kivy through this: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/. I couldn't get the link on the official site to download as a package.

Comment: You should also install pygame via that same site (and make sure the versions match), did you do that?